# Imbalanced aspect ratio of input in CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Consider the following model using keras in TensorFlow.

```py
Conv2D(
    filter = 2^(5+i)    # i = num of times called conv2D
    kernel = (3, 3),
    strides = (1, 1),
    padding = 'valid')

MaxPooling2D(
    pool_size = (2, 2))
```

```
Layer                 Output Shape    Param
-----------------------------------------------
L0:  Shape            (50, 250, 1  )  0
L1:  Conv2D           (48, 248, 32 )  320
L2:  MaxPooling2D     (24, 124, 32 )  0
L3:  Conv2D_1         (22, 122, 64 )  18496
L4:  MaxPooling2D_1   (11, 61,  64 )  0
L5:  Conv2D_2         (9,  59,  128)  73856
L6:  MaxPooling2D_2   (4,  29,  128)  0
L7:  Conv2D_3         (2,  27,  256)  295168  !!
L8:  MaxPooling2D_3   (1,  13,  256)  0
L9:  Flatten          (3328)          0
L10: Dense            (512)           1704448 !!!
L11: ...
```

Here, an input shape with ratio of 1:5 is used. After `L8`, there cannot be any more convolutional layers as one side is `1`. Actually in cases where `input_side < kernel_size`, there can be no more convolutional layers; the layer is forced to be flattened into a vector with high number of units – resulted from the large shape [1][3] and the large number of filters [2] deep into the network. The `Dense` layer [4] follows will have a high number of parameters that requires a lot of computation time.

To reduce the number of parameters specific to the problems (highlighted in [x]) above, I think of these methods:

1. Adding a (1, 2) **stride** to early layers of `Conv2D`. (Refer to [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299171/how-to-train-a-cnn-with-non-squared-data))
2. Reduce the number of **filters**, say, from [32, 64, 128, 256, ...] to [16, 24, 32, 48, ...].
3. **Resize** the input data to a square-shaped input so that  more `Conv2D` layers can be applied.
4. Future reduce **the number of units** in the first `Dense` layer, say, from 512 to 128.

My question is, will these method work and how much will they affect the performance of the CNN? Is there any better approach to the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can try 'same' padding instead of valid. It will save you from these diminishing numbers you are getting, somewhat.

For point 1:

Adding a non-uniform stride is only good if your data has more variation in a certain direction in this case, horizontal.

For point 2:

The number of filters don't help or hurt the way your dimensions are changing. This would hurt your performance if your model was not overfitting.

For point 3:

Resize the input to square shape would seem like a good idea but would lead to unnecessary dead neurons because of all that extras you are adding. I would suggest against it. This may hurt performance and lead to overfitting.

For point 4:

Here, again the number of units don't change the dimensions. This would hurt your performance if your model was not overfitting.

Lastly, your network is deep enough to get good results. Rather than trying to go smaller and smaller. Try increasing your Conv2D layers in between the MaxPools, that would be much better.

Comment: Note that the question asks about ways to reduce the number of parameters, in which case methods 2 and 4 do in fact help.

Comment: Thanks. Will a non-uniform stride cause any information loss in one axis? I am hesitant to use stride (1,2) in the first few layers just to uniform the dimensions.

Comment: Yes, it would lead to loss of information in the dimension you are taking a bigger stride. But, if data in that dimension is redundant then it may help. You need to observe your data for that.